# configuring mysql on my Windows Server 2003

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-server-2003

I have a Windows Server  with the following options:

5 GB RAM 
XeoN 31220 3.10GHz

Windows Server 2003

im trying to configure mysql on my server that i did it as the follow:
My.ini:

```
[MySQLD]
port=3306
basedir=C:\\Program Files\\Parallels\\Plesk\\Databases\\MySQL
datadir=C:\\Program Files\\Parallels\\Plesk\\Databases\\MySQL\\Data
default-character-set=latin1
default-storage-engine=INNODB
read_buffer_size=10M
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
sort_buffer_size=256K
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=1M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
innodb_log_file_size=10M
innodb_thread_concurrency=8
max_connections=100
old_passwords=1
max_user_connections=500
thread_cache_size=4
thread_stack=196608
binlog_cache_size=32768
net_read_timeout=30
net_retry_count=10
net_write_timeout=30
thread_concurrency=10
open_files_limit=0
[client]
port=3306
```

my question is this configuration method my.ini fit to my server or can i optimize it by difference values bcoz my server work so slowly thank you

Comment: my question is this configuration method my.ini fit to my server or can i optimize it by difference values bcoz my server work so slowly

thank you

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what your server role is.

I mean if it's dedicated MySQL DB or share resources with other tiers like Application server or web server.

Other important thing is for what purpose it DB optimized.

It can be development machine, OLAP (data warehouse), OLTP (lot of concurrent transactions), etc ...

Also what storage type server has, there are some performance tuning details if you use InnoDB storage engine or MyISAM.

I don't think there is answer in one sentence ;)

You can read this articles which helps you tune-up/optimize performance to fits your needs:

http://mysqldatabaseadministration.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-optimization-and-tuning-guide.html

http://www.notesbit.com/index.php/web-mysql/mysql/mysql-tuning-optimizing-my-cnf-file/

Answer (score 0):

Even though my answer not about tuning performance in Windows 2003 server, it pointing the reason and possible work around as i found with my reading.

MySQL 5.5 InnoDB uses mutex implementation on Windows with [CriticalSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682530%28VS.85%29.aspx); as found major performance issue before 5.5.  If you are using prior to 5.5, upgrade to 5.5 to get that performance fix.

And part of the further performance gain achieved with [condition variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682052%28VS.85%29.aspx) on Windows Vista or newer Windows operating systems. Condition variables are not supported on Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP.

So, If this slow performance found with MySQL 5.5, Simple solution is moving to Windows 2008 Server. Main performance lagging because of Critical Section wait queue.

See further reading : https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=238505812835782